# VS 2012 Build Error: RdlCompile: Could not open file ".....rdlc"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I am trying to build my `ASP.NET 4.0` project in `VS 2012`, but I am getting similar error for every `rdlc` file I have in my project:

```
Error   5   RdlCompile: Could not open file "obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Accounts\Report\ConsolidatedFeeReceipt.rdlc". Could not find file 'F:\Projects\SAPNETS_Redesigned\SAPNETS_Redesigned\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Accounts\Report\ConsolidatedFeeReceipt.rdlc'.   SAPNETS_Redesigned
```

This same project is working flawlessly in some other machine. Can anybody please help me out?